# Play DivX 3 low motion too

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I've just set up a RaspBMC and I wanted to play a movie. Unfortunately, it just showed a gray screen and played sound.

I've found out, that the movie's codec is DivX 3 Low motion, which is unsupported because of a license issue.

But I have 60 GB content, and I don't want to convert it.

Is there any solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you want to convert it? It looks like an older codec.

Comment: I hope, you can read: "But I have 60 GB content, and I don't want to convert it."

Comment: I can... which is why I asked.

Comment: Because it takes much time :D Calculate: 130 episodes remaining, Avidemux writes 17m/episode, if we sum: 1.534 day

Comment: I suspect it will be worth it, as the GPU is closed the only way to get accelerated playback is to use the Foundation's licensed codecs. VLC may play it, but I suspect it will be unbearably slow.

Comment: Which licenced codec do you mean?

Comment: The licences on sale here: http://www.raspberrypi.com/

Comment: Yes I heared these, but non of them is unlocks the DivX 3 Low, 'cos they are for other things, right?

Comment: Correct. As I said, you won't get accelerated playback because you can't buy licences, which is why I would encourage you to convert. Having said that, VLC may play it anyway if you're lucky, but it will only be using the CPU.

Comment: And otherwise why are these things locked?

Comment: DivX3 is a proprietary codec, designed by Microsoft.

Comment: Do you have a Linux PC?

Comment: Know that Video standard is H.264 then it could be worth re-encoding and would only take a batch file to process a few a day and you will have it done in a week.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Oh, MS sucks. Yes, I have a Linux machine too.

Comment: @Hellonearthis I've calculated with Avidemux, it takes only 1.534 day (about a day, 13 hours). So I can't use Raspberry Pi to convert it, right?

Comment: Use a normal computer, its more powerful and goes way faster than the raspberry Pi (just saying). Maybe re-download your movies in the new supported codec (mkv, H.264)? I did that with my 200GB collection, took some time but saved me from converting everything. :)

Answer (score 3):

if you have a linux I made this script (ToH2364.sh) which look for all avi file and convert only the ones using divx3 codecs (msmpeg4) it could help

./ToH264.sh RootPathOfTheSearch extensionToLookFor ExtentionOfTheEncodedFile CodecToCheck

example

./ToH264.sh /media/HDD/ avi mp4 msmpeg4

but only the directory is mandatory so it could simply be:

./ToH264.sh /media/HDD/

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> # erease result file
> echo "Result File" > ToH264.result
> #Get the forlder to search
> fld="$1"
> #Get the extension to look for if it exist, else look for "avi"
> if [[ $2=="" ]]
> then exti="avi"
> else exti=$2
> fi
> #Get the futur extension for if it exist, else set "mp4"
> if [[ $3=="" ]]
> then exto="mp4"
> else exto=$3
> fi
> #Get the codec to look for if it exist, else look for "msmpeg4"
> if [[ $4=="" ]]
> then cdc='msmpeg4'
> else cdc=$4
> fi
> # exe the search and save the result in TpH264.tmp
> find $fld  -name "*.$exti" > ToH264.tmp
> #convert each result stored in the file ToH264.tmp if it use the specified codec and if the output file doesn't exist
> while read line
> do
>    if avprobe -show_streams "$line" | grep $cdc
>    then
>            echo "$line"  >> ToH264.result
>            no | avconv -threads 8 -i "$line" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy "${line%.*}.$exto"
>    fi
> done < ToH264.tmp
> ```

Comment: I signed up just to say, "You sir, are a god"

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner log version
Adds runtime stats
Adds _converted tag to mark output files and make sure not to overwrite input ones:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Required Ubuntu Packages
#
# libavcodec-extra-53 libav-tools
#
# Examples:
# ./toh264.sh /media/HDD/ avi mp4 msmpeg4
# ./toh264.sh /media/HDD/



# erease result file
echo "Converted Files" > ToH264.result
#Get the forlder to search
fld="$1"
#Get the extension to look for if it exist, else look for "avi"
if [[ $2=="" ]]
then exti="avi"
else exti=$2
fi
#Get the outcome file extension if it exist, else set "mp4"
if [[ $3=="" ]]
then exto="mp4"
else exto=$3
fi
#Get the codec to look for if it exists, else look for "msmpeg4"
if [[ $4=="" ]]
then cdc='msmpeg4'
else cdc=$4
fi
# exe the search and save the result in TpH264.tmp
find $fld  -name "*.$exti" > ToH264.tmp

#convert each result stored in the file ToH264.tmp if it use the specified codec and if the output file doesn't exist
while read line
do
   if [ x$(avprobe -show_streams "$line" 2> /dev/null| grep $cdc) != "x" ]
   then
           echo "Converting" $line
           echo "$line"  >> ToH264.result
           avconv -stats -threads 8 -i "$line" -c:v libx264 -crf 20 -c:a copy "${line%.*}_converted.$exto"
   fi
done < ToH264.tmp
```