# RaspBMC plays some avi files but not others

Tags: raspbmc, video, media

I have a Pi version A (256MB), running RaspBMC (I guess the latest version as I only created the SD a month or so ago).

When I try to play some AVI files I have no problems adn everything works fine.  When I try to play others I can hear the sound but the image stays on the navigation screen, without freezing so I can still scroll around and access sub-menus. Any idea what may be causing this behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: Will these same files play okay on a Windows, (or other 'package system') without issue?  You may want to try one of the many video repair systems out there, and also verify that you have the correct codecs installed.

Comment: I can play the files fine in VLC on Ubuntu 12, which I have running on my laptop.  How can I check that I have the correct codecs installed? (my mouse does not seem to want to work when I connect it to the Pi I am just using a remote control).

Comment: Sounds like it is not a file issue then... That is a good question... One that I don't have the answer to...

Comment: If in VLC you go to `Tools` > `Codec Information` it should tell you what CODECs are being used for the file, it does sound like the AVI in question uses a video CODEC RaspBMC does not have installed

Answer (score 6):

This sounds very much like some of your AVI files have video encoded with MPEG-2 or VC1 (or possibly some other unsupported codec) and you don't have the MPEG-2 or VC1 codec installed (only h.264/MPEG-4 content can be played by default). I had exactly the same issue when I first installed RaspBMC and tried to play DVD content (it plays like an audio file, in the background, as you describe). The [RaspBMC FAQ](http://www.raspbmc.com/wiki/user/frequently-asked-questions/) says:

> Q: Can Raspbmc play back MPEG2 or VC1?
>
> A: Yes! Raspbmc offers hardware decoding of these codecs, provided the
>   codec pack has been purchased from the Raspberry Pi foundation website
>   [here](http://www.raspberrypi.com)

You can find out the particular codec you need by opening the "Media Information" window in VLC then clicking the "Codec Details" tab (the screenshot below was taken on a Mac, but I imagine the Linux version will be similar). The video stream is usually Stream 0. If its MPEG-2 or VC1 then you should be able to purchase a codec and play it just fine.

[image]

Note that (at time of writing) the Raspberry Pi does not support playback of files encoded with the DIVX3 codec, which appear in VLC as type "MPEG-4 Video v3 (DIV3)".  This [Raspberry Pi forum topic](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=17443) has a reply from dom (near the bottom) which confirms this:

> That is not MPEG 4 compliant and not supported. DIVX3 is actually a
>   codec reverse engineered from an old Microsoft codec, than was a
>   non-standard variant of MPEG 4. The hardware codec can't support it.

In order to get around this, you should be able to re-encode the file to one of the supported formats. The answer to [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/play-divx-3-low-motion-too) includes a script that claims to convert from DIVX3 to H.264 (which then should be playable on the Pi without purchasing a codec). It looks like it uses [avconv](http://libav.org/avconv.html#Synopsis) to do the legwork. I've not tried it, so use at your own risk.

The How-To Geek article [How to Add MPEG-2 and VC-1 Video Codec Support to Your Raspberry Pi](http://www.howtogeek.com/137654/how-to-add-mpeg-2-and-vc-1-video-codec-support-to-your-raspberry-pi/) contains an excellent tutorial on what to do from here, but in a nutshell, once you've purchased the relevant codec, the license file will get emailed to you. You can then install the codec by following the instructions in the How-To Geek article above or [How Do I Add Codecs?](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspbmc/FAQ#How_do_I_add_codecs.3F) section of the [RaspBMC/FAQ](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Raspbmc/FAQ).

Comment: I have checked it VLC and it appears to be using MPEG-4

Comment: Stream 0:
  Type: Video
  Codec: MS MPEG-4 Video v3 (DIV3)
  Resolution: 512x384
  Frame rate: 23.976000
  Decoded format: Planar 4:4:0 YUV
Stream 1
  Type: Audio
  Codec: AS2 Audio (aka AC3) (a52)
  Channels: Dolby
  Sample rate: 48000 Hz
  Bitrate: 192 kb/s

Comment: Unfortunately, according to [this post](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=6231&pid=50513#pid50513) it seems you have a DIVX3 file and this format isn't playable on the Pi. Looks like you might have to re-encode it instead.

Comment: Just to add to my comment above, [this Raspberry Pi forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=17443) from dom (near the bottom) confirms it: _"That is not MPEG 4 compliant and not supported. DIVX3 is actually a codec reverse engineered from an old Microsoft codec, than was a non-standard variant of MPEG 4. The hardware codec can't support it."_

Comment: Thanks for all the help guys, now just one last question.  How would I re-encode the file?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1909/play-divx-3-low-motion-too) includes a script that claims to convert from DIVX3 to H.264 (which then should be playable on the Pi without purchasing a codec). It looks like it uses [avconv](http://libav.org/avconv.html#Synopsis) to do the legwork. I've not tried it, so use at your own risk.

Comment: I used the script in binarybobs link. Took a little playing with but then worked fine. (I think this topic can now be marked as answered or closed etc)

Comment: Then you should mark that answer should as correct

Comment: I've now added the information in my comments to the answer for completeness, so feel free to mark as correct :-)

Answer (score 1):

I've used Any Video Converter, it's a Windows programs that gives many options when converting.  http://www.any-video-converter.com/products/for_video_free/

Answer (score 1):

Use [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/) on your desktop to re encode the files in question.